# What is the limit for requests to Bitfinex via Sockets?

Tags: node.js

According to the documentation there a limitation for REST API to Bitfinex:

> If an IP address exceeds 90 requests per minute to the REST APIs, the requesting IP address will be blocked for 10-60 seconds and the JSON response {"error": "ERR_RATE_LIMIT"} will be returned. Please note the exact logic and handling for such DDoS defenses may change over time to further improve reliability.
>   For users who need high-frequency connections, please switch to the WebSockets APIs.

But what is the limit for order count via Socket API (v2) using NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I found that request limit is 500 orders per 10 mins, but after a minute or 2 of the ban, you can post 500 requests more.